# CSS3: Is it possible to pause OTHER elements' animations on hover of an element?

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to make a carousel with CSS only. I'm to the point where I have an image slider with each image linking to another page. It looks great but I want to add controls. I've made "buttons" under the image slider and I have them animated to light up in sync with the slider (1st button lights up when 1st image slides in, etc.). Is there any way I can make each of the buttons functional by creating a hover statement that will pause the animations of the other buttons as well as the slider? And I guess more importantly, can I make a click statement that will cause the image slider to skip to the appropriate place in its animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: NO. it is not possible.

What you're looking does not exist: you need a :has - selector.

```
<div id="container">
  <span id="content">content</span>
  <span>id="button">button</span>
</div>

<!-- non-functional css -->
#container:has(#button:hover) > #content
{
    background-color:red; <!-- or: stop animation -->
}
```

The has-selector DOES exist is JQuery (http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and might be implemented in future css-versions. It is hover not included in css3. It appears to be included in css4:
http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors/#has-pseudo

Comment: @Roko C Buljan: thanks for your suggestion. I changed the link and started with the short answer: NO. even with the not-selector.