# Stop animation on another element hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to stop when hovering left button.

Here is my code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rpQoKz

My slideshow does not stop on my last styling rule `#container:has(#carousel-left:hover) > .photobanner`

I have read it might not exist and tried to work with :has selector [post about :has selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988971/css3-is-it-possible-to-pause-other-elements-animations-on-hover-of-an-element). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your html like this

```
 <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div id="container">
   <a class="left carousel-control" id="carousel-left" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" id="carousel-right" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    <div class="photobanner">
        <img class="first-image active" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/13034/sticker.png" alt="" />
        <img src="https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/photobanner/image-3.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/13034/sticker.png" alt="" />
        <img src="https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/photobanner/image-3.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/13034/sticker.png" alt="" />
        <img src="https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/photobanner/image-3.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/13034/sticker.png" alt="" />
        <img src="https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/photobanner/image-3.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/13034/sticker.png" alt="" />
        <img src="https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/photobanner/image-3.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

and css

```
#carousel-left:hover ~ .photobanner{
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```